# 05 Acura RSX type s engine mount failure

Tags: acura, motor-mounts, rsx

Passenger side engine mount has failed 3 times after Clutch replacement each time mount was replaced with a new one that exceed OE specifications.

What is causing the mount failure?

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: It could be a bad mount design, hard acceleration all the time, that or poor clutch engagement habits